# Firebase Push Notification wrong message

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am able to trigger the push notifications, but i get **this site has been updated in the background** instead of the actual message.

The service worker code :

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.7.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.7.1/firebase-messaging.js');
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
apiKey: "**************",
authDomain: "push-notifications-240e1.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://push-notifications-240e1.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "push-notifications-240e1",
storageBucket: "push-notifications-240e1.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "********"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Comment: it seems to be working fine in localhost but not in sandbox url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have fixed the issue, The service worker file had been cached. I will close this question now. I fixed it by adding the file in cache control.